Execution Plan with Laravel Eloquent?
I am using Laravel 9.
I have built an API that connects to our clients SQL Server Databases for queries.
I want to be able to run a execution plan on a SQL Server script, in hopes to find any missing indexes.
After alot of research this is what keeps coming back to achieve my goal
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

function getExecutionPlanWithIndexes($query)
{
    // Enable STATISTICS XML to capture the execution plan with index suggestions
    DB::connection('sqlsrv')->statement('SET STATISTICS XML ON;');

    // Run the query - this should return the execution plan with potential missing index recommendations
    $plan = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select($query);

    // Disable STATISTICS XML after retrieving the plan
    DB::connection('sqlsrv')->statement('SET STATISTICS XML OFF;');

    // Display the XML execution plan
    return $plan;
}

// Example usage:
$executionPlan = getExecutionPlanWithIndexes("SELECT * FROM your_table");
dd($executionPlan);

However, this is always just returning the results of the query not the execution plan,
If I open SSMS and run the same raw script, if does give me both the execution plan and the results.
I have tried looking for 3rd party packages that can help but I am not having much luck, can anyone help?

I'm no lavarel expert but could it be that every DB::connection(...) thing creates a new connection, which would mean that SET statisticS XML statement is wasted. Can you create a single DB::connection(...) thing and use it for multiple statements instead. I question why you would use laravel for these kind of raw level things though

Thank you for the reply, your theory on the connection on the statement being wasted if each line is a new connection is very interested and something I am going to look at now.
To answer why I am using Laravel to do this, our whole API is build with Laravel, how we handle the connections to different clients databases are all build into our Laravel project.

Use this
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->statement('SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;');
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->statement('SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;');

SHOWPLAN_XML to capture the execution plan without running the query

Thank you,
Doing this in SSMS only returns the execution plan,
However in Laravel its still giving me the results.
